# Saving edit widget setting in style or layer definition file?

Tags: qgis, editing

I am using QGIS 2.4 on Windows 7 installed by the OSGeo4W-installer.

I want to save the "edit widget"-settings in a style to use them after loading in a different vector layer.

The problem: If I change the "edit widget"-setting in the layer properties (category "Fields") and save them in a style (QGIS layer style) or a layer definition file, the settings are not maintained when I load the style at a different vector layer (shp) or I open the layer definition file once again. It seems that the "edit widget"-settings are only be saved in the qgis-project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has been resolved very recently and will hopefully be included in the next major release (QGIS 2.6) in October: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11123

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems it wasn't fixed. Layer Definition Files still not retaining the fields edit widget settings in 2.6. It does stay when using a .qml style file.